# What was Tamar's capital crime?

Tags: halacha, parshanut-torah-comment, halacha-theory, parashat-vayeishev

On what basis did Judah have the right to sentence Tamar to be burned (Genesis 38)? What capital offense did she commit?

Answer (score 4):

Her trial was done by the fact that she was obviously pregnant and it was known that she had not married the son of Yehuda. Thus, as the daughter of a priest who had committed znus she was subject to being burned.

[Rashi Vayeishev 38:24](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8233/showrashi/true#v24)

> **and let her be burned:** Ephraim Miksha’ah said in the name of Rabbi Meir:
>   She was the daughter of Shem, who was a priest. Therefore, they
>   sentenced her to be burned. [From Gen. Rabbah 85:10]

Ramban says that she was judged guilty of מורדת במלכות and מבזה את אביה הכוהן which allowed Yedudah (as the מלך) to decree her punishment

[Ramban Vayeishev 38:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.38.24?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=bi)

> אך כמבזה את המלכות ועל כן כתוב ויאמר יהודה הוציאוה ותשרף כי באו לפניו
>   לעשות בה ככל אשר יצוה והוא חייב אותה מיתה למעלת המלכות ושפט אותה
>   כמחללת את אביה לכבוד כהונתו

Comment: Is a bat kohein shomeret yavam chayevet sereifah? Is being pregnant in general sufficient evidence of znus? How do we know she wasn't raped? How do we know she was warned?

Comment: In the pshat it seems that the problem was that she was betrothed or at least promised to Shelah and went and committed znut - the pregnancy was simply an indicator of this fact. So it's more like אשה מאורסה שזינתה.

Comment: @DoubleAA I added the Ramban who disagrees with this and gives his own reason. I accidentally posted this before I added the Ramban.

Comment: @Harel13 Ramban says that a shomeres yibum is not subject to misah and gives a different pshat.

Comment: @sabbahillel even before Matan Torah? That is what we're dealing here - don't forget that there are Canaanites involved in this story. This is shomeret yibum according to Canaanite laws...

Comment: @Harel13 There are those that say that the avos did keep the mitzvos even before matan torah. That would seem to be the way Rashi learns. According to the Ramban, the melech would have the authority to do this even before matan torah as the halacha of bnei Noah to set up a court system.

Comment: @sabbahillel was Yehudah considered the king of those people? I'm not really sure. Were all those people following Bnei Noach law? Also unclear.

Comment: @Harel13 It is a machlokes whether the shvatim were considered Bnai Yisrael or Bnai Noach. In either case, once Tamar married the son of Yehudah she was a member of the shevet and under his authority as the head of the shevet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107840/discussion-between-harel13-and-sabbahillel).

Comment: Just because you kept the Torah then didn't mean you could impose punishment on someone else who wasn't.

Answer (score 4):

None. Baal HaTurim says "burning her" meant branding, not execution.

If we accept Baal HaTurim's premise that the practice pre-Sinai was to punish failure-to-keep-the-family-name-alive with branding, i.e. permanent humiliation, you can see how the Torah instituted a far less extreme form of that with chalitzah -- a public shaming, with no corporeal punishment.